# ajax cannot clear my ul when error comes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i have a code adding data using ajax in laravel. Now when i tried to put a valid data, my ajax will return alert success class , if error it will give me alert danger class and list all errors from fields in `<li>` now my problem is when first i inputted correct data's , my alert success works fine and give me an alert message of success, now when i duplicate my data, it will return me error and my `<li>` list is not emptied. The success message that i appended wasn't cleared.

Here is my code:

```
function addCategoryAjax(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.print-error-msg ul').empty();
    $.ajax({         
        url: "{{ route('admin.addcat') }}",        
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#frmAddcategory").serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
             if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                $('.print-error-msg').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
                $(".print-error-msg").addClass('alert alert-success');
                $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
                $(".print-error-msg").css('display','block');
                $(".print-error-msg").append('<li>'+data.success+'</li>');
                }else{
                printErrorMsg(data.error);
            }
        }
    }); 
}

function printErrorMsg (msg) {

            $('.print-error-msg').removeClass('alert alert-success');
            $(".print-error-msg").addClass('alert alert-danger');
            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
            $(".print-error-msg").css('display','block');
            $.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
                $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
            });
}
```

my code above shows the append from `li` the messages. why is this `$('.print-error-msg ul').empty();` doesn't work.? Any suggestions?

Here is my view:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="margin-top: 6px;">
       <div class="print-error-msg" style="display:none">
           <ul></ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have u try to remove `style="display:none"` see if it work?

Comment: You call the empty() method once in addCategoryAjax() but when do you call addCategoryAjax() again?

Comment: You already did that before ajax call `$('.print-error-msg ul').empty();` ,so it must be clear your ul . The problem may be here when you success you append like this `$(".print-error-msg").append('<li>'+data.success+'</li>');` should append in `ul`

Comment: have you tried  `$('.print-error-msg ul li').remove();`?

Comment: @DavidJorHpan i put it at top because that ajax is from a buttom submit. every time i click the button i want to clear the <li> element of ul from .print-error-msg div

Comment: @ShadowFiend still doesn't work

Comment: I think I know now.. when you print the error message.. You don't have the empty in your print error message function..  but i'm not sure..

Comment: $('.print-error-msg').removeClass('alert alert-success');
            $(".print-error-msg").addClass('alert alert-danger');
            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
            $(".print-error-msg").css('display','block');
            $('.print-error-msg ul li').remove();
            $.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
                $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
            });

still doesnt work

Comment: how about the `$('.print-error-msg ul').empty();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the correct data, you append `li` to the `.print-error-msg`, not the `ul`:

```
$(".print-error-msg").append('<li>'+data.success+'</li>');
```

So, when get the error data, empty the `ul` will not work, your code:

```
$(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
```

instead modify the append `li` to `$(".print-error-msg ul")`:

```
$(".print-error-msg ul").append('<li>'+data.success+'</li>');
```